# Compare tables with unordered columns on DataGrip

Tags: database, datagrip

I have this situation on DataGrip where I want to compare two tables that holds the same columns but created in different order.
The compare tool of DataGrip looks to be order dependent (which makes sense) and so I can't compare my tables properly without dragging each columns one by one to finally achieve a true comparison.

for ex.

```
table A
a, b, c, d, e, f

table B
e, b, f, c, d, e
```

The point is that my tables have about 150 columns. It's a nightmare to sort by hand..

Is there any option to sorts the columns order or something like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare not only tables but result-sets. So, create an ordered result-sets via SQL and then compare them.

Comment: Ok this is clever. I would add that the request can be generated easily with DataGrip's auto completion on the star (*)